#IndexError: list index out of range
以前使用していたコードでGoogle ColabからStable Diffusionを起動できなくなっています。
この状況について、解決方法はありますか？
対応をお願いいたします。
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-31e191356cea> in <cell line: 45>()
     65     time.sleep(4)
     66     with open('/content/srv.txt', "r") as file: text = file.read()
---> 67     srv= re.findall(r"https?://(?:\S+?\.)?trycloudflare\.com\S*", text)[0]
     68
     69     for line in fileinput.input('/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gradio/blocks.py', inplace=True):

IndexError: list index out of range



Google Colab の設定手順です。
→Connect Google Drive： Done
→Install/Update AUTOMATIC1111 repo： Done
→Requirements： Done
→Model Download/Load（Use_Temp_Storage:に☑、PATH_to_MODEL:にパスを貼り付け）
→ControlNet： Done
→Start Stable-Diffusion（Use_Cloudflare_Tunnel:に☑） の流れで進めました。

「以前使用していたコードでGoogle ColabからStable Diffusionを起動できなくなっています。」とのことですが、掲載のコードとStable Diffusionとは無関係に見えます。テキスト処理の問題に見えますが違いますか？正規表現を見直してみてはどうでしょうか？テキストの内容とやりたい処理が不明なのでこれ以上は分かりません。

fast-stable-diffusion/fast_stable_diffusion_AUTOMATIC1111.ipynb at main · TheLastBen/fast-stable-diffusion に同じコードがあります。Notebook の中身を読むと、nohup cloudflared tunnel --url http://localhost:7860 > /content/srv.txt 2>&1 & という処理で /content/srv/txt を作成しています。おそらく、Cloudflare Tunnel を利用するための何らかのサーバがローカルで動作している(localhost:7860 で接続待ち)ことが前提の様です。

該当のコードは質問者自身が自分で書いたものですか？もし第三者が作ったプログラムを動かしているだけなのであれば、該当コードの作者に報告するか修正されるのを待つのが正攻法な気がします。 / metropolis さんが言及しているリポジトリで既に Issue として報告されているようです。https://github.com/TheLastBen/fast-stable-diffusion/issues/2915

皆様、ご返信ありがとうございます。 私は初心者なので、このコードは自分で書いたものではありません。 該当コードの作者には既に報告いたしました。


IndexError: list index out of range

ってのは、配列なりリストなりで、要素数を超えてアクセスしようとしたときにそういうエラーが出ます
ってことで

srv= re.findall(r"https?://(?:\S+?.)?trycloudflare.com\S*", text)[0]

でこのエラーが出るってことは、
re.findall(r"https?://(?:\S+?.)?trycloudflare.com\S*", text)
の返り値が空になってるんでは。
そこら辺チェックしてみよう
